# When using initial caps, which words should be left un-capitalised?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Initial caps, otherwise known as title case, e.g. "When Using Inital Caps, Which Words Should Be Left Un-capitalised?".

Which words should be un-capitalised?

**Edit** I gather this differs between UK and US ...