# How to capitalize first letters in titles?

Tags: capitalization, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Often words in titles has its first letter capitalized, but some don't (such as "The Title of This Question"). What are the rules for which words to capitalize?