# Rules for capitalization in presentation titles

Tags: capitalization, heading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Hi everyone,

I am German and the German language follows very strict rules of capitalization: A word starts with an upper case letter if its a noun or at the beginning of a sentence. In the English language however, nouns are usually written with a lower case letter at the beginning.

But right now I am working on the slides for a presentation and I wonder what the rules for capitalization are in titles? I do have a template here and on that it looks like in titles all nouns are written with an upper case letter in front. Is this true? What is the general rule here?