# What words are not capitalized in titles?

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

For instance:

*The Story of a Boy who Likes Pancakes and is Hungry* <- (completely random made-up title)

In this example "of, "a", "who", "and", and "is" are all not capitalized. I'm fairly sure this is correct but I'm not 100% positive about "who". In any case, is there some kind of list of what words are not capitalized in titles, or how do you know when not to capitalize specific words?

Comment: Again, please use the search function: 1. [Which words in a title should be capitalized](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/); 2. [rules for capitalization in presentation titles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/)

Comment: *The Story of a Boy Who Likes Pancakes and Is Hungry*. All verbs should be capitalised, including *is*.