# Title Capitalization Doubt: "If" or "if?"

Tags: capitalization, headline-case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Suppose I'm going to write an article/essay with the following title:

***"What To Do If You Believe Space Aliens Shot JFK"***

Does the word "if" get capitalized, like above, or not?

Comment: Capitalize (it is neither a preposition nor an article).  I would have said to migrate the question to writers, though.  But I see it *came* from there.

Comment: @GEdgar - Grammar and usage questions are off-topic at Writers. Style questions are a bit of a grey area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *if* is typically capitalized in titles.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Titles):

*In English, the first word and the last word of titles should be capitalized. In addition, all **nouns**, **pronouns**, **adjectives**, **verbs**, **adverbs**, and **subordinate conjunctions** should be capitalized. Articles and coordinating conjunctions are not capitalized, while sources disagree on the capitalization of prepositions.*

"If" is a subordinate (also, subordinating) conjunction and as such should be capitalized.

Comment: The most disputable preposition is _"of"_. Since it resembles _"if"_, it creates confusion around this issue: according to the strictest rules, "if" should be capitalized while "of" shouldn't! Symmetrically that just looks wrong when you see it on paper.