# Section titles capitalisation: in text and in table of contents

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Could you please tell me: What is the recommended capitalisation style for the section titles of a business document and a scientific text (PhD thesis)---first caps or sentence style? And if I use the first caps in the titles in the document, should I also use first caps in the table of contents?

Comment: This is a question of style. Check the question this has been closed as a duplicate of. More to the point, consult a faculty member, or look at papers in your own field in order to decide anything definitively. These kinds of conventions vary within fields and subfields, so you should see what your peers do.