# Why Start Each Word in a Title with an Uppercase Letter?

Tags: capitalization, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

I'm not a native speaker of English, and I've asked myself a lot why on many (most?) blogs, all  words in an article’s title (except some little words like "of", "for", "with", ...) start with an uppercase letter. From my point of view it makes it less readable. But maybe it's a grammatical rule I don't know.

Example: 
http://nytimes.com/

Comment: This [link](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/592/1/) should answer your question (maybe some others, too); scroll down to where it says "**The major words in the titles of books, articles, and songs**..."

Comment: Please visit Writers.SE where this and many other related topics are covered.

Comment: @jwpat7, good find. My question is also about why such a rule in blogs (as it makes things less readable in my point of view).

Comment: @jptsetung - it makes the important parts of the title stand out - think of it as tag highlighting

Answer (score 2):

The New York Times is not a blog, it's a newspaper that has an online version. Those are [headlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline), and that is how headlines are written.

More specifically, that is how headlines are written according to the [AP (Associated Press) Stylebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_York_Times_Manual_of_Style_and_Usage).

Comment: It's far more common in US style than British English style.

Comment: "This is how it's done" is not an answer to "Why is it done?"

Comment: @tenfour: My mother would not agree with you – at least, not at those moments when she told me, "_Because I said so_." :^)  In any case, I think "This is how it's done" is fine when the O.P. asks, "Maybe it's a grammatical rule, I don't know."

Comment: I was thrown by OP's labeling of the Old Gray Lady as a _blog_.

Comment: It’s the same capitalization as used for the titles of books, movies, and plays.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Not in my (British) experience. It is normal to capitalise all the words of a title (excluding articles – "the", "a" – etc.). Certain publications (in a wide sense) chose their own style to override the usual convention – much as some do with other capitalisation uses.