# What is the Rule for Capitalizing Titles

Tags: capitalization, titles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

First of all, after knowing the answer, I may need to edit the title of this post as the very first thing :)

Moving to my actual question, which groups of words in the title should be Capitalized. I know, all nouns have to be, any other parts of speech?

Comment: The rule, if any, is for what words **need not** be capitalized.