# "Create an Account" or "Create Account"

Tags: articles, capitalization

I have a registration form I want to name.

Should I name it:

> –  “Create Account”
>
> –  “Create an Account”

(or “Create the Account”)

Also, which words should be capitalized if this is a header.

Comment: To answer the capitalisation question: [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In titles, labels, and captions like that, we routinely omit articles and other words not essential to the meaning in order to keep it short. So if you were writing a sentence, you would write, "Create an account". But for a label you would normally drop the article.

In titles we usually capitalize the first letter of each word, except for articles, conjunctions, and prepositions (unless the article, etc, is the first word of the title, in which case it is capitalized). For example, "The Care and Feeding of Rabbits" or "History of the English People". (Sometimes these words are capitalized when they are considered important. Like, "Strange But True" -- you don't want the reader to skim over the "but" or he'll completely miss the point.)

Thus, the conventional thing to use would be, "Create Account". No article, both words capitalized.

If you do decide to include the article, it should be "Create an Account". Article not capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- create an account
- create account
- create new account
- create a new account

"Create the account" is grammatically correct, but is rarely used.

Capitalization is up to you. You may leave capitalization altogether, if you want. But remember one thing: you can either capitalize just the first word or capitalize all (you may or may not capitalize the articles - a, an).

Comment: There's no linguistic problem with *Create the account*, but there may be a philosophical one, that 'the' account can't be referred to until it has been created...

Comment: I was hoping for a sole answer as to which one I should use.

Comment: @ChenHarel The answer is "which ever you want, except the one that uses *the*"

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, articles are omitted in labels. Apple uses the following style (assuming it's a computer form):

> Create Account
>    Delete Account

Answer (score 1):

I think

> create an account

is better, in fact the best among your options, assuming that we are referring to a single account.

And

> create the account

should only be used, when you are referring to an account you have mentioned earlier.

As far as capitalization is concerned, I agree with our friend rudra.