# Capital letters in headlines

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-english

I’m not a native English speaker. I’ve noticed that in titles or headlines,  many words often start with a capital letter while others are still lowercase. As an example, the title of my question would most likely be:

> Capital Letters in Headlines

I already found a [solution on how it’s done](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized), but I still want to know why.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I don't think you will find a linguistic "Why" for this. There are no "rules": some journals follow conventional title-casing, others do not. What a headline is intended to communicate is only incidentally its linguistic content; the primary "content" is "You would be interested in reading this", which is communicated as much by attention-getting typography as by the words.  Consequently, I think this question is off-topic.

Comment: In addition, I invite you to visit, and possibly support, the proposed [**English Language Learners**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) site. It may well be below-grade for you; your contribution as one who **has learned** English would be valued.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what question is being asked here.  Are you asking for what the rules are for determining the case of words in a newspaper headline or a journal article, or some such?

Comment: @tchrist I want to know why capitalisation in headlines is done differently from the "normal" grammatical rules.

Comment: I think the question is *Why are so Many Words Capitalized in American Publications?* (as opposed to, say, British publications, which tend only to capitalise proper nouns)

Comment: @StoneyB Your first comment might already be the answer I was looking for. If the answer is that there is no formal answer I can see why the question could be considered off-topic. But I think it could still help others who ask themselves the same question.

Comment: I think that's why, across SE, such questions are closed but not deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case#Headings_and_publication_titles), this phenomenon is called *title case*, and:

> Among U.S. book publishers (but not newspaper publishers), it is a
>   common typographic practice to capitalize "important" words in titles
>   and headings. This is an old form of emphasis, similar to the more
>   modern practice of using a larger or boldface font for titles.

So, basically, it's done for emphasis.

Comment: It's done by many U.S. newspaper publishers, as well (but usually not by U.K. ones).

Comment: I have never seen a book ***not*** titled in title-case.  That would be Wrong. I believe this answer misrepresents what is going on.

Comment: @tchrist [A certain well-known publisher has one](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do) -- but I only know that because I happen to have a copy on my desk! And then there's [this one](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=159420411X), although Amazon list the title in conventional American form. A British listing would probably be different.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree with you; I was also surprised to see that Wikipedia focusses so much on US as opposed to UK publishers. I publish frequently with UK houses and title casing is very common. Still, my point still holds: it's for emphasis.