# Should I capitalize peace, love, and happiness?

Tags: capitalization

I am writing in our family Christmas card this year:  Wishing you peace, love, and happiness.  My question is, should peace, love, and happiness be capitalized?  It's driving me crazy!

Thank you!

Comment: Whichever you choose, I bet nobody returns them with a comment on non-standard punctuation. Reg gives the 'correct' answer, but if you want to outmanoeuvre him, _and_ add emphasis, use a ridiculous font (with 'Cow-spots', I don't think many people can tell capitals from uncials anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You do not capitalize random words in the middle of a sentence. That includes *peace*, *love*, and *happiness*. In German, the nouns, and all nouns, would be capitalized. In English, they'd only be capitalized in a title, and [even there not necessarily](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized).