# How should I capitalize "Keep On Running/Keep On Moving" and "Walk On Down"?

Tags: british-english

These are the song titles by Spencer Davis Group/Deep Purple and Aerosmith accordingly, I know that if a preposition is a part of a phrasal verb it is capitalized, but everywhere I look, I see "Keep on Moving" (I'm guessing by the logic of importance of words) and so on, what is the correct variant here?

Comment: I think the disconnect here is that in the context of those song titles, the *on* is a simple preposition, and not part of a phrasal verb like "Keep On".

Comment: To me, the non-capitalised version *"Keep on Running"* suggests the title of a text written by Mr. Keep, concerned with his views/advice for people who want to take up running/jogging.

Comment: @DanBron It seems to me that in the last one 'Walk on down', the 'on' is acting differently to the way it is in the other two. 'Keep on running/moving' are grammatically-correct imperative sentences in which the 'on' signifies continuity of something that is already happening. 'Walk on down', whilst it is idiomatic, is not signifying any continuity. The three words, it might be argued,are a phrasal verb.

Comment: related: [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized/91#91)

Comment: One of the answers in the linked question specifically covers albums and band names; and they all mention that it's a matter of house style.