# Should I capitalize the word "on" in this title?

Tags: capitalization

Should it be "Alive on Arrival" or "Alive On Arrival"?

Comment: Hi Ryan, this question might be helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

No, 'On' shouldn't be capitalized unless it is used adjectivally or adverbially.

'Capitalize the first word of the title, the last word of the title, and all nouns, pronouns, verbs, adverbs, adjectives, subordinating conjunctions, and a few conjunctions. Prepositions are only capitalized if they are used adjectivally or adverbially.'

[Grammar Girl : Capitalizing Titles](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/capitalizing-titles)

Comment: Is Grammar girl a web site? If so, make that a link.