# Is the contraction of "and", "'n'", capitalized in a title?

Tags: capitalization, contractions, titles

Should it be, for example, "Fish 'n' Chips", or "Fish 'N' Chips"?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized if in any doubt about 'and'. I think the contraction of 'and' should be treated the same as 'and'.

Comment: I think this question is topical (as in, there's probably some established best practice or orthographic rule, here), but in order to remain open and get answers, @Ryan, you're going to include some evidence that you tried to answer this question yourself first.  What did your prior research tell you?

Comment: @Avon It's worth noting that that's not always the case. The band Guns N' Roses, for example, capitalizes the "n."

Comment: Names and trademarks are different from common phrases. You can call yourself (or spell, or orthograph yourself) any way you like.

Comment: @Nicole It is a good example but I have always felt the capital N seemed wrong in their name and, apart from that, what bib said.

Comment: It seems like most uses of "n" for "and" are in names and trademarks, though: Pick 'n Save, Cash 'n Carry, etc. Since some of them may choose to capitalize the "n" and some may choose not to, there's probably no one black-and-white answer to this question.

Comment: Agree, @Nicole.  However, I think that *'n'* is such a tiny word that capitalizing it makes it too much 'in your face'.

Comment: A capital n in phrases like these is **just marketing**. It has zero to do with anything else at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about taking a regular, lowercase phrase, like *fish 'n' chips* or *rock 'n' roll*, and putting it in a book title—say, *Bottomfeeder's Guide to Fish 'n' Chips* or *My Ten-Year War with Rock 'n' Roll*—it seems to me that *'n'* is preferable to *'N'*. That's because *'n'* is a diminished form of *and*, which would normally be lowercased in a title if it were included in its entirety. It doesn't make much sense to me that removing two of the three letters in a conjunction would provide a compelling justification for capitalizing the remaining letter.

On the other hand, if you are asking about how to handle *'n'* when it appears in a proper name, all bets are off. A quick look at fish 'n' chips outlets in the San Francisco Bay Area reveals the following treatments: [Blue Bay Fish & Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/bluebay-fish-and-chips-antioch#p1Voa9bfq3W0wnAHE2nutQ), [Camelot Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x808f7ba7562dc32b:0x1ecb83993a02474e!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3DeQxbZdTcTr0AAAQfCZAVEw%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sCamelot+Fish+%26+Chips+Pacifica,+CA+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=yXOUVZ_WJNLSoASq-4LADw&ved=0CBIQoiowAA), [The Codmother Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x808580e3c1e4e48d:0x50128cc247105805!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3DkKYKxWpUg68AAAQJOM37NA%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sThe+Codmother+Fish+and+Chips+San+Francisco,+CA+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=jnOUVdnANcjEogSJ1oPoAw&ved=0CBIQoiowAA), [Fish 'n Frites](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/fish-n-frites-half-moon-bay-2#fBY67h2diLsbj6sWli3lug), [HS Fish & Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/hs-fish-and-chips-el-sobrante#w6G9nFYtzZEX7LVY0ZHVQg), [H.Salt, esq. Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x808578219801eff7:0x1ed2e67c4a94ad10!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3DLsETl5vmdo0AAAQY_n6p6g%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sH.+Salt+Fish+%26+Chips+Richmond,+CA+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=83GUVaT-PJewogS-6qLIAQ&ved=0CBIQoiowAA), [Jay's Fish & Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/jays-fish-and-chip-hayward#UBOk6rbDkT6npdfF6Ntn9w), [Jonathan's Fish & Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/jonathans-fish-and-chips-menlo-park#yDL9c-QodsfHu9G0a1tFeA), [London Fish N' Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/london-fish-n-chips-hayward#bvFmrPGVzs3tm8nHUnHqJw), [Louisiana Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x808f80aa8e8741af:0xe4793e79f0d1d2c1!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3DRnlr5Ghiu2MAAAQZFDjbAQ%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sLouisiana+Fish+%26+Chips+Oakland,+CA+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=VHOUVZuLOszxoATzw6WACA&ved=0CBIQoiowAA), [Piccadilly Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x80858094e8d8d65d:0x673e8e285431fdee!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3DE94HicjydtcAAAQYKEq6Sw%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sPiccadilly+Fish+%26+Chips+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=O3KUVf6EI8rEogT66IGIBw&ved=0CJMBEKIqMA8), [[Sausalito] Fish & Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/fish-and-chips-of-sausalito-sausalito#NV6QLBBGOsPjUM1vKk-ZvA), [Scousers Fish 'n Chips](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/scousers-fish-n-chips-concord?select=pL-_XZlJbKpEmH-2Ok80Rw#PnUOXDmV5UawnFbnEGrfCQ), [Tugboat Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x80856134d0c298bf:0x4fab3a2831ffadf1!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3DkfIE94a-xyAAAAQYW9Sc6A%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sTugboat+Fish+%26+Chips+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=b3KUVa_uE9bqoATW0bRQ&ved=0CI4BEKIqMAs), and [Union Fish & Chips](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?hl=en&pb=!1s0x808f902fe66e9a8b:0xbd3705b87766f677!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e1!4shttps://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?output%3Dtile%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.gps%26panoid%3D4DkJ2SF6U5AAAAQYHgxdYg%26x%3D0%26y%3D0%26zoom%3D3!5sUnion+Fish+%26+Chip+San+Leandro,+CA+-+Google+Search&sa=X&ei=8XOUVe2KNsO1oQSS_IigAw&ved=0CBIQoiowAA).

For those of you not keeping score at home, that adds up to twelve ampersands, two instances of *'n*, and one instance of *N'*. Neither *'n'* nor *'N'* scores any matches at all. So if you're giving your fish 'n' chips shop a name, you can use *&* or you can use *n* or *N*, presumably with as many or as few apostrophes as you like.