# Crisp 'n Dry naming

Tags: apostrophe

Is the **'n** in Crisp 'n Dry vegetable oil a messed up contraction of *"and"* ?

Or is it supposed to indicate **on** or **in** or some such?

See http://www.crispndry.co.uk/

[image: logo]

Comment: Well, only they can say for sure, but "and" is the most likely meaning by far. That is how most people will understand it.

Comment: The contraction of *and* to *'n* is mentioned in these other questions: [Is the contraction of “and”, “'n'”, capitalized in a title?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256269),  [What rules determine the apostrophe placement in “ham 'n eggs” and similar expressions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55855) I have never seen *'n* used as a contraction of *on* or *in.*

Comment: That is an accepted (in the US, at least) contraction of "and".

Comment: ...although there is no objective reason it couldn't be short for, say, _onion_.

Comment: @Rathony That's about punctuation though and the fact that the apostrophe is sometimes put in different places.

Comment: @Araucaria The way I see the question is (1) It is a question about a trade mark. There is no rule governing naming or writing a trademark. I don't think the following questions would work here. Why is **i** in **iPhone** in lower case? What does it stand for? Is it a short form of internet? How come it could be shorted to **i**? and so on. The question should be asked of the company who created this trademark. That's why I don't think it has anything to do with English Language and Usage. I think Sven Yargs nailed it in the above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many words such as *and* or *can* have two sounds in English. They have a strong form when stressed or precede an ellipsis or a pause. For these two words these strong forms are /ænd/ and  /kæn/respectively. However, these words are normally not stressed. When these words occur in their normal form they have a reduced form, called a *weak form*. For these two words these forms are /ən/ and  /kn/. Notice that the word *and* doesn't have a strong A sound here. Also it has no /d/ either. This is the way that we actually pronounce this word in normal speech, it's just that we don't normally notice. The 'n' in Crisp 'n Dry is meant to be a snappy reproduction (I assume)  of the way that we actually pronounce this word in real speech. There are many other examples. There are thousands of chip shops in the UK with *Fish 'n Chips* painted on their frontage.