# Capitalizing Call to Action Text

Tags: capitalization

I am a web developer and was working on a website that is in both German and English. As my partner (native German speaker) and myself (native English speaker) were looking through the site he noticed a capitalization error in the German version. He then switched to the English version and asked me if the way I capitalized the call to action is correct, in English.

In this case, the phrase is `Request a Quote`.

To better understand how it is presented, below is a screenshot:

[image: Request a Quote Screenshot]

My thought is that call to actions should be treated [like a title](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14/47987). Is this correct? Should call to actions be capitalized or should they be lowercase (`Request a quote`)?

Comment: Choose a style guide that you like, and follow it. There is no authority for questions like this.

Comment: What Coin Fine said.  This is a display issue for website headings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not considered to be a title, the correct phrase should be "Request a quote", since 'quote' here is a common noun and shouldn't be capitalized. If you were to consider the phrase to be a title, however, "Request a Quote" is the correct way to write it.

A call to action is a marketing term, not a grammatical one. And hence there is no hard and fast rule to follow in this case. Depending on the style guide you are following or your aesthetic taste, you are free to choose between the two.

As a fellow designer, I'd go for "Quote", though.