# When using the title "Webmaster" is the first letter capital?

Tags: capitalization

Trying to clarify whether the first letter in the title of *Webmaster* is capitalized? I am referring to a title listing and not when used in a sentence.

Comment: Most words in a title are capitalized. So yes, this would be capitalized too. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized

Comment: The link from @ralph.m deals with mostly AmE capitalization, and in my experience, BrE capitalization rules differ.

Comment: Not significantly, though—certainly not in regard to this question.

Comment: What is a "title listing"? Could you give an actual example? Perhaps you could consider the nominated duplicate; it's likely to provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Webmaster* should only be capitalized when used as a formal occupational title.

Comment: Prove it :)​​​​

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the context.

For example, if you refer to THE company webmaster, it's capitalized; for ONE OF the company webmasters, it's not:

- Poudlard Webmaster, Harry Potter
- James Bond, a MI6 webmaster