# How does capitalizing helps readers?

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-case

I have seen many articles' titles, with almost all words having the **first letter** capitalized.

For example:

- [9 Things You Should Tell Your Boss At Your Next Performance Review](http://www.forbes.com/sites/dailymuse/2014/03/12/9-things-you-should-tell-your-boss-at-your-next-performance-review/)
- [Going Public Isn’t Selling Out, It’s The Best Way To Stay Alive](http://techcrunch.com/2015/12/09/going-public-isnt-selling-out-its-the-best-way-to-stay-alive/)
- [12 Ways to Make Work-Life Balance a Reality—and Not Just a Buzzword](https://www.themuse.com/advice/12-ways-to-make-worklife-balance-a-realityand-not-just-a-buzzword)

We can see many examples where many *seriously* big publishers follow this trend. There is something common they're following, but I can't figure out what.

## Question:

> Does capitalizing affects a user's readability? If not, why is it common amongst big publishers?

Note: The links are given as examples.

Comment: I can give many examples where all *seriously* big publishers follow this trend. There is something common they're following. I'm not able to figure out what?

Comment: I am aware of the migration history of the question. The problem is that "is it readable" is a completely different question from "why is it used". The second is on topic here, the first back on UX, but none is on topic on both. I made an edit which left the "why" part. Student, you can ask again the other part on UX, this wouldn't be cross posting because it would be a separate question. You'll have to focus on "are there studies comparing the readability" without asking why it has become a standard (which, as a history of language, has nothing to do with UX).

Comment: Note that this question is not about what "title case" is called or which words are capitalised. It's about why it's done; why that style was adopted.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes, you're correct. The curiosity is about *why* not what

Comment: Many [British newspapers](http://www.theguardian.com) don't follow this trend.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm asking **why** the (ones who use it) use it? My question is about easiness for end users of the product.

Comment: I'm just saying that ***not*** all seriously big publishers follow this trend, contrary to your comment above.

Comment: @PeterShor Oops, [updated](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/293252/revisions) question. Thanks a lot for correcting me!!

Comment: I see this question was migrated from UX SE. Perhaps, this question can be migrated to Writers SE? IMO, capitalizing the first letter of (almost) all words is bad practice. May be a/ It's easy on the eyes b/ It grabs your attention immediately... These would be my best guesses