# Are chapter headings and other semantically smaller parts as the title capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, titles, book-title, headline-case

I found the question [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized) Regarding the number of answers votes and also according to my personal taste I like to capitalize titles. But what exactly are titles? Only the single main book title? What about other smaller semantic parts? Chapter headings, sub-chapter, ...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The finer points of capitalization are a matter of style; you should observe the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adhere to the guidance of the [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to CMoS and APA (two popular style guides), some lower-level headings aren't capitalised in headline-style.

[Chicago Manual of Style 16th edition](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/717/2/) (headings by level):

> 1. Centered, Boldface or Italic Type, Headline-style Capitalization
> 2. Centered, Regular Type, Headline-style Capitalization
> 3. Flush Left, Boldface or Italic Type, Headline-style Capitalization
> 4. Flush left, roman type, sentence-style capitalization
> 5. Run in at beginning of paragraph (no blank line after), boldface or italic type, sentence-style capitalization, terminal period.

[APA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/16/) (headings by level):

> 1. Centered, Boldface, Uppercase and Lowercase Headings
> 2. Left-aligned, Boldface, Uppercase and Lowercase Heading
> 3. Indented, boldface, lowercase heading with a period. Begin body text after the period.
> 4. Indented, boldface, italicized, lowercase heading with a period. Begin body text after the period.
> 5. Indented, italicized, lowercase heading with a period. Begin body text after the period.