# Should I capitalize "all" in titles?

Tags: capitalization, parts-of-speech, headline-case

Let's say I have a title "full legal names of all sellers"

Should I capitalize it as

a) Full Legal Names of **all** Sellers

or

b) Full Legal Names of **All** Sellers

?

I have doubts as "all" is not a noun here but rather a modification for a noun "sellers". Am I wrong?

And yes, I've read [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: And yes, I've read https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14/238670

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bquery%5D=All

Comment: @Stan: then why are you asking? *All* is an adjective, and adjectives are  capitalized.

Comment: How exactly does the duplicate fail to answer your question?

Comment: If the only choices you are accepting opinions about are "Full Legal Names of all Sellers" and "Full Legal Names of All Sellers," then yes, the second option is generally preferable, given that most style guides wouldn't endorse lowercasing the first letter in _all_ just because (a) it's a short word or (b) it's an adjective. (Note, too that earlier in the title you have the word _Legal_, which is also an adjective, initial-capped.) But many headlines online and in newspapers are rendered in sentence case, like this: "Full legal names of all sellers." So that's another possible option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is ***yes***, and here's the reasoning:

In a title, adjectives, verbs, pronouns, etc. (pretty much all words except for prepositions and articles, such as *the* and *an*) are capitalized. As you said, *all* is modifying the word sellers. That makes *all* an adjective, and it would, therefore, be capitalized. *Full* and *legal* are adjectives as well, and see how they are capitalized as well.

Let me know if you have any questions!