# Should the modal verbs be written in lowercase or uppercase in a title?

Tags: capitalization, modal-verbs, headline-case

Let us take this title for example, " The Cars should Be sold in Three Years".
If lowercase or uppercase rules are from the *Chicago Manual of Style*, the word *should* is lowercase or uppercase?

I have browsed this website and seen [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized), but the answers there do not mention modal verbs.

Comment: Thanks for your website. I have browsed, yet the modal verbs are not included. That is why I put up this question.

Comment: I see, so you're unsure if "modal verbs" are included in the category of verbs (like how "dwarf stars" are a subset of astronomical "stars") or not (like how "sea stars" are not a subset of astronomical "stars").

Comment: Sorry,  I am not so clear of your words. Would you please express your thought in an easier way？And my specifis question is: " should the words like 'must', ‘should’, 'could', 'might', 'would' be capitalized  or not in an article title"

Comment: I thought that the linked post gave the answer, because I think of modal verbs as verbs. I would say that 'must', ‘should’, 'could', 'might', 'would' should be capitalized according to the *Chicago Manual of Style* rules, because those rules say that all verbs should be capitalized.

Comment: Uh… I can imagine many US American papers following that and I won't be surprised if many others don't.

Few British editors would give those rules house room.

Comment: Now I understand whether they are written in lowercase or uppercase should follow the specific rules for a certain publishing company.