# What is the proper way to cite a title of a poem, written in lowercase, from a book of poetry using MLA?

Tags: mla, sic

If the title of the poem were "apple and trees," would it be best to write it as "[A]pple and trees," or is there a preferred method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)

Comment: I suspect that many people would regard the capitalization of the titles of poems by e e cummings to be an atrocity.

Comment: Related: [Is the book title “God versus gods” grammatically incorrect?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559334).

Answer (score 3):

The *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.) 1.2 Titles of Sources (emphasis mine):

> Whenever you use the title of a source in your writing, take the title from an authoritative location in the work, not, for example, from the cover or top of a page. Copy the title **without reproducing** any unusual typography, such as special capitalization or *lowercasing of all letters*.

In other words, MLA says to ignore the unusual lowercasing and present it as you would any other title.

In this case, the title would be cited as *Apples and Trees*.