# Is the book title "God versus gods" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: nouns, capitalization, titles, religion, book-title

I wrote a book entitled *[God versus Gods](https://amzn.to/36a05Kt)* which depicts the struggle between the One God of Jewish Monotheism and the multiplicity of gods in the pagan/polytheistic ancient world. The prevailing rule in English is to capitalize nouns in titles of books. According to that, the word "gods" in my book's title should be capitalized.

However, there is also a rule in English that one should capitalize Divine nouns and pronouns when referring to God or anything related to Him. Without getting too much into the ideology behind the title, I wanted to purposely NOT capitalize the word "gods" in order to deemphasize their actual existence. Thus, my question is whether *[God versus gods](https://amzn.to/36a05Kt)* can be considered a grammatically-correct title for the book? Or do we say that since nouns in a book title must be capitalized, then the words *gods* should be capitalized as *Gods*?

Comment: It's your book so it's your choice

Comment: Capitalization is not a matter of grammar, it's a matter of stylistic convention and as such, there may be countless notions of what's correct.  Typically in title case, all words with more than three letters are capitalized, so it would be "God **V**ersus Gods."  How to get someone to respect your non-standard capitalization (for instance, if you're the author bell hooks - not Bell Hooks) is an interesting question, but not one that's well suited to this site.

Comment: @Juhasz Usually, conjunctions are not capitalized in book titles. Hence, I didn't ask about "versus."

Comment: Related: [What is the proper way to cite a title of a poem, written in lowercase, from a book of poetry using MLA?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451981).